# serialport reading each character individually

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I am trying to read bytes from a serialport and write them to a textbox as a string.

My problem is that the code writes each letter/character individually into the box, instead of one long string, so if I recieve "Hello" it will write "H", then clear the box, then "e"..etc

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static SerialPort serial;
        public string line;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inputBox.Text = "Enter some text, then press enter";

            serial = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            serial.Open();

            serial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serial_DataReceived);
        }



        public void serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            // wait for the buffer
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[serial.BytesToRead];
                serial.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                line = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

            if (line != null)
            {
                writeRecieved(line);
            }
        }


        public void writeRecieved (string line)
        {
            if (outputBox.InvokeRequired)
            {
                outputBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { outputBox.Text = line; });
            }
            else
            {
                outputBox.Text = line;
            }
        }
```

However, when debugging, it appears to only hit each of these lines once, and the local view shows the variable line as "Hello"

*EDIT:*
I tried append (outputBox.Text += line;), however the textbox fills up with text each time a new message is received. I tried putting an outputBox.Clear(); in the datarecieved handler, but it does this after each byte for some reason

Comment: Why don't you append the character instead of replacing the entire textbox string..? Why not do `outputBox.Text += line` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer is capable of reading data much faster than 9600 bps. When it calls `serial.Read`, it reads as many characters as are available in the buffer *at that time*.

So you either need to keep reading until you get a newline, or do as suggested in a comment and append the text read to the textbox.

In response to your question in the comment, what you're asking for isn't possible. The receiver can't know when the sender is finished sending all of the data, unless the sender includes some end-of-text character. The sender might send `"Hello"` and then follow immediately by `"World"`. The data is received character-by-charecter. Unless the sender sends some kind of terminator after each word, it's just a stream of bytes to the receiver.

Yes, the `Thread.Sleep` is inefficient and shouldn't ever be used for this kind of thing.

Typically, this kind of thing is handled by making the sender add newline characters at the end of each line. The receiver can then read characters and split the received text on the newlines to derive the lines.

Using a `Sleep` can get you into trouble, too. Suppose the sender sends `"Hello"` followed by `"World"`, and for some reason your thread sleeps for, perhaps 4320 ms (could happen on a busy system) rather than 300, and you get `"HelloWo"` as the first word. Oops.

Comment: Is there a way of checking when the datarecieved event has finished, and thus the buffer is full? The current " System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);" is not efficient

Comment: Thanks very useful, learned a lot. I added Environment.NewLine to the end of the sent string, then used serial.ReadLine(); to make sure i got the whole lot.